# Parsing json with autocomplete functionality

Tags: jquery

It might be a duplicate question but I am stuck with parsing json. Since I am intermediate with jQuery so I fall to the problem.

I am implementing autocomplete with CakePhp.

my response function returns correct json. Here is my function

```
    public function jsonSongs() {
        $json_output = '';
        $role = $this->Auth->user('role');
        $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $condition = array("Song.name LIKE " => "%" . $this->request->data['Song_name'] . "%");
        $song_name = $this->Song->find('list', array('conditions' => $condition, 'limit' => $this->request->data['Song_maxRows'], 'recursive' => '-1', 'order' => 'Song.name'));
        foreach ($song_name as $key => $name) {
            $json_output[] = array("id" => $key, "label" => $key." - ".$name, "value" => $name);
        }
        echo json_encode($json_output);
        $this->layout = $this->autoLayout = $this->autoRender = false;
    }
```

Returned json is

```
[{"id":8,"label":"8 - .Dhal gayaa aafataab ai saaqii","value":".Dhal gayaa aafataab ai saaqii"},{"id":32,"label":"32 - a.nga.DaaI par a.nga.DaaI letii hai raat judaaI kii","value":"a.nga.DaaI par a.nga.DaaI letii hai raat judaaI kii"},{"id":34,"label":"34 - aa.Nkh ko jaam samajh baiThaa thaa a.njaane me.n","value":"aa.Nkh ko jaam samajh baiThaa thaa a.njaane me.n"},{"id":35,"label":"35 - aa.Nkh se aa.Nkh milaa baat banaataa kyuu.N hai","value":"aa.Nkh se aa.Nkh milaa baat banaataa kyuu.N hai"},{"id":36,"label":"36 - aa.Nkh se duur naa ho dil se utar jaayegaa","value":"aa.Nkh se duur naa ho dil se utar jaayegaa"},{"id":37,"label":"37 - aa.Nkho.n kaa thaa qasuur naa dil kaa qasuur thaa","value":"aa.Nkho.n kaa thaa qasuur naa dil kaa qasuur thaa"},{"id":38,"label":"38 - aa.Nkho.n me.n jal rahaa hai kyuu.N bujhataa nahii.n dhu.Naa","value":"aa.Nkho.n me.n jal rahaa hai kyuu.N bujhataa nahii.n dhu.Naa"},{"id":39,"label":"39 - aa.Nkho.n se yuu.N aa.Nsuu .Dhalake","value":"aa.Nkho.n se yuu.N aa.Nsuu .Dhalake"},{"id":40,"label":"40 - aadamii aadamii ko kyaa degaa","value":"aadamii aadamii ko kyaa degaa"},{"id":41,"label":"41 - aae hai.n samajhaane log","value":"aae hai.n samajhaane log"},{"id":43,"label":"43 - aah ko chaahiye ik umr asar hone tak","value":"aah ko chaahiye ik umr asar hone tak"},{"id":44,"label":"44 - aaho.n me.n hai asar magar farq asar asar me.n hai","value":"aaho.n me.n hai asar magar farq asar asar me.n hai"}]
```

and finally my jquery function is ..

```
           $(function () {
            function log(message) {
                $("<div/>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
                $("#log").scrollTop(0);
            }

            $("#song").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        minLength: 2,
                        method: "post",
                        url: "<?php echo HTTP_PATH; ?>/songs/jsonSongs",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        data: {
                            'Song.maxRows': 12,
                            'Song.name': request.term
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                        alert( obj.id === "8" );
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.label,
                                    value: item.id
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    log(ui.item ?
                        "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                        "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
                },
                open: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
                },
                close: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
                }
            });
        });
```

I want to show suggestion and when user click on any it just writed to hidden text box. I can't even alert my json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `ajax` request `url` is on same domain then do the followings and check

1. change `dataType: "jsonp",` to `dataType: "json",`
2. Add `header('Content-type: application/json');` before `echo json_encode($json_output);`
3. Remove `var obj = $.parseJSON(data);` `alert( obj.id === "8" );` No need to parse

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Va8E5/)**

Comment: it halts me with error in FireBug console. `TypeError: e is undefined`

Comment: I have done this

n (result) {
                            var data = $.parseJSON(result);
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
//                                    console.log(item.id + " - "+item.label);
                                    return {
                                        label: item.label,
                                        value: item.id
                                    }
                                }));
                            }

THough issue is solved but how can I write it to hidden text box.

Comment: What you want to store in hidden text?, if you want to store label then you can do like this `$('#hiddenInputId').val(item.label);` replace `hiddenInputId` with your hidden input `id` and this will set last item label as hidden input value

Comment: I have seleceted it as correct but I had to add the statement ` var obj = $.parseJSON(data);` else it halts me with error I have mentioned in my first comment.